# Code Signing breaks Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, .net, isolatedstorage

I'm using Isolated Storage via the IsolatedStorageFile.GetMachineStoreForAssembly() method to store my application settings.

After my application was already deployed, I bought a digital certificate to sign my software with. However, the new version with the certificate cannot read the old settings file. Presumbly this is because the signing changed the application identity.

How can I access the old settings, which were written from the old version (which was unsigned)? Is it possible to somehow get the Machine store of the old assembly by passing in the old identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine store is identified by application **identity**, not just **name**.
Your publicKeyToken would be different after you signed your code.

References:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getmachinestoreforassembly(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getmachinestoreforassembly%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yt6ck0.aspx

- Edit -
  This is one of the down sides of isolated storage.  I don't use it for permanent settings, that cannot be reentered if necessary.  For longer term storage I create a folder for my app under  the ApplicationData folder 
  `Environment.GetFolderPath(ApplicationData)` and store my files there.

That being said, I found [this](http://skysigal.xact-solutions.com/Blog/tabid/427/entryid/1647/-NET-IsolatedStorage-Location-changes-when-Assemblys-Major-Number-updates.aspx) article that can sometimes be used to locate the folder, *if* you know the name of a file.

Comment: This doesn't appear to provide any information that isn't already in the question, and it does not answer the question "How can I access the old settings?".  It *might* be good as a comment, but -1 as an answer.

Comment: Ben, he edited the answer, and now it does answer the question.
The solution from the linked article is that if you know the name of the file (I do), you can get the location of isolated storage for the current assembly. From that, you guess where the isolated storage for all assemblies must be and look for the file with the correct name.
That sounds like a hack, but I guess it would work in most circumstances. Maybe someone knows a better solution, though?